# How to display a character when a value in the same row is the highest value in its column?

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following example table:

```
A | B    
a | 5    
b | 3    
c | 1    
d | 9  <=== expected result   
e | 0    
f | 4
```

So it should display `d` as in the other column `9` is the highest value.

Comment: Best practice is to mark the answer as best answered, so that future readers can benefit as well.

Comment: Read more [about] that in our [help].

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following formula to accomplish that.

### Formula

```
=QUERY(B2:C7, "SELECT B, C ORDER BY C DESC LIMIT 1")
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Explained

The `QUERY` formula shows column B and C, sorts the range descendingly (`ORDER BY`) and limits the result to just one row (`LIMIT 1`).

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[find max and show row](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdFluanFUS2VDVHVGLUJOd0I5UWdfaWc&usp=sharing)**

Answer (score 1):

An alternative ("Excel style"):

```
=index(A:A,match(max(B:B),B:B,0))
```

`max(B:B)` to find the maximum value in ColumnB (ie `9`)

`match(max(B:B),B:B,0)` to find the row number where there is an exact match for `9` (the first found)

`=index(A:A,match(max(B:B),B:B,0))` to apply that row number (relative to the start of B:B) to ColumnA (relative to the start of A:A) and return the value there - `d`.